# Strange layers in GeoServer 2.8

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, boundless-suite

We are using OpenGeo suite 4.6 (GeoServer ver. 2.8) using PostreSQL ver 9.6 on Windows Server 2012 R 2.

We are publishing layers on GeoServer, while publishing layers found some strange layers (attached as screenshot)

Does any know what it is exactly? 
is there any kind of layers or views?
[image: GeoServer strange layers]

Comment: They appear to be unique layer names, what happens when you publish them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have SQL views configured in your server? If so, that might be the cause, there is code that temporarily configures a layer with a UUID generated name, computes the view attributes using it, and then it should remove it right away.

GeoServer 2.8.x has not been supported for a while, you might want to look into an upgrade.

Comment: will this cause a problem in general function of geoserver ? which geoserver would you suggest for up gradation for production.

Comment: I should not cause issues. I'd upgrade to a 2.11.x series (e.g., 2.11.1)